# How do you add a new API entry to the directory?

Tags: google-api

This is a surprisingly simple question, but I am unable to find the answer despite a solid search.

How are APIs added to the Google APIs Explorer Directory?

Comment: Google APIs Explorer only supports Google APIs, so I would assume Google Devs add new APIs. Random people can't add APIs to the Explorer Directory, if that's what you're meaning.

Comment: Yes this is what I am asking; perhaps that answer the question then! One cannot add a record to the list. Unless we have a way to request an API be added?

Answer (score 0):

Google has an api called the [google discovery services api](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/reference/apis) this api contains a list of most of their apis

So by adding a record for a new api in descovery services it shows up in [explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer)

Comment: Thank you, this does get me a bit further towards adding a new record, however exploring the google discovery services does not appear to provide a clear answer to this question. Where does one add the record?

Comment: you do not have access to add a record these are Googles apis not yours.   you would probably need to get a job at google working on one of their new apis.

Answer (score 0):

Only Developers at Google can add an entry to the Google API Directory